# `solana program deploy` stuck

Tags: solana-program, deploy

From yesterday I haven't been able to deploy (upgrade) my program to solana mainnet. The deploy works fine on devnet, with the same binary. But when running `solana program deploy` on mainnet, it is stuck after a while, with the following message:

```
 1.7% | Sending 199/905 transactions             [block height 234210965; re-sign in 0 blocks]
```

This is very odd since the last time my deployment failed it actually did output `Blockhash expired. 5 retries remaining` or something along the line, but now it is stuck at 0 blocks forever. My account on explorer site shows only a couple of transactions sent (about 10 txns), while a successful deployment would send hundreds of transactions. I've tried upgrading the solana-cli to match the cluster version, even switching to another machine but it didn't help. Does anyone have a workaround?

```
❯ solana --version
solana-cli 1.17.22 (src:da2078d4; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the solana cli version v1.14.18

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.18/install)"
```

Then you can run the deploy command again, it seems to be faster than 1.16 and 1.17 https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/32595#issuecomment-1682448390

I had the same issue and downgrading worked for me

Comment: Wow, I did exactly this and was able to deploy prior to reading your answer. Thanks anyway!